# Flattening nested dictionary React? - Cannot read property 'standard' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working on a personal WebApp project in React. I am new to this technology but very eager to learn it. I came across a problem. I am using axios to fetch data from Google YouTube API response and it works but I am unable to parse obtained data that is nested. What I mean by that:
Inside Items there are multiple snippets

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "snippet": {
                "title": "Dolby Atmos - usłysz więcej!",
                "description": "W dzisiejszym odcinku opowiem wam o tym czym jest nagłośnienie i system dolby atmos. System i nagłośnienie Dolby atmos znajdziemy obecnie w najlepszych kinach. System wspierają takie filmy jak \"Zjawa\" czy \"Kapitan Ameryka wojna bohaterów\". Jakość dźwięk docenią kinomani i prawdziwi audiofile. Istnieje również stworzenia systemu składającego się z głośników dolby atmos kina domowego, ale jest poważna inwestycja.\nJeżeli jesteś z Łodzi i chcesz poczuć Dolby Atmos na własnej skórze kliknij tutaj:\nhttp://www.helios.pl/47,Lodz/StronaGlowna/\n\nJeżeli dzisiejszym odcinek Ci się spodobał zostaw like'a albo subskrybcję :D\nFanPage:\nhttp://facebook.com/RuchOpornikow\nGoogle+:\nhttps://plus.google.com/u/0/+RuchOpor...\nTwitter:\nhttps://twitter.com/RuchOpornikow",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "standard": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QWTk3vnztRw/sddefault.jpg",
                        "width": 640,
                        "height": 480
                    },
                    "maxres": {
                        "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QWTk3vnztRw/maxresdefault.jpg",
                        "width": 1280,
                        "height": 720
                    }
                },
                "resourceId": {
                    "videoId": "QWTk3vnztRw"
                }
            }
        },
```

I want to get a random snippet from items and use it's title attribute, description and thumbnails.
At this point I can access description and title but accessing `movie.description.thumbnails.standard.url` or `movie.resourceId.videoId` gives me an error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'standard' of undefined
  31 |     backgroundPosition: "center center",
  32 |   }}
  33 | >
> 34 |   <img src ={`${movie.thumbnails.standard.url}`}/>
  35 |     <div className="banner_contents">
  36 |     {/* edge cases */}
  37 |     <h1 className="banner_title">
```

Here is my full code :

```
function Banner() {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get("./data.json");
      setMovie(
        request.data.items[
          Math.floor(Math.random() * (request.data.items.length-1))
        ].snippet
      );

      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
  return (
    <header
      className="banner"
      style={{
        backgroundSize: "cover",
        // backgroundImage: `url("${movie.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url}")`,
        backgroundPosition: "center center",
      }}
    >
      <img src ={`${movie.thumbnails.standard.url}`}/>
      <div className="banner_contents">
        {/* edge cases */}
        <h1 className="banner_title">
          {movie.title}
        </h1>
        <div className="banner_buttons">
          <button className="banner_button">Play</button>
          <button className="banner_button">Original</button>
        </div>
        <h1 className="banner_description">{movie.description}</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="banner--fadeBottom" />
    </header>
  );
}

export default Banner;
```

Do you know what could be an error and how to fix it? `Console.log` and `JSON.stringify` show that those attributes are there.

Comment: Your `movie` state is an array, but you reference into it like it is an object in your render logic. `movie.snippet` and `movie.thumbnails` will obviously be undefined.

Comment: How to access those elements?

Comment: Answered below, but on the initial render `movie` is an array and won't have the properties I called out. Converting it to an empty object would get you closer but would delay the "undefined"-edness when referencing further into your state object, thus the addition of some null checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue(s)

Your initial `movie` state is an array, but you reference into it like it is an object in your render logic. `movie.snippet` and `movie.thumbnails` will obviously be undefined.

```
const [movie, setMovie] = useState([]);
```

and

```
movie.thumbnails.standard.url
```

## Solution

1. Make the initial state type match what it is updated to from the fetch request and how it's accessed in the render logic, i.e. an object

   ```
   const [movie, setMovie] = useState({});
   ```
2. Use proper null checks and provide fallback values.

Null Checks

```
movie.thumbnails && movie.thumbnails.standard && movie.thumbnails.standard.url || ""
```

or using Optional Chaining and Null Coalescing

```
movie?.thumbnails?.standard?.url ?? ""
```

Comment: So what i did wrong was trying to access an element of array as if it was a js object but element was simply not there because of the data-structure nature. And the solution was to access change type from [ ] to { } object, is that correct?

Comment: @szymonindy Yes, that was half the problem. Objects are associate arrays of key-value pairs, you can think of arrays as special objects where the keys are the array index. The array would not have an index named "thumbnails", i.e. `movie["thumbnails"] // undefined`. When you access deeper into an undefined object that is when you'll see the error you had.

Answer (score 0):

initial `movie` is an empty array and it will take some time to fetch from API. refactor to the below

```
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState();
```

and check movie if it's not null before rendering

```
return movie?(
<header
  className="banner"
  style={{
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    // backgroundImage: `url("${movie.snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url}")`,
    backgroundPosition: "center center",
  }}
>
  <img src ={`${movie.thumbnails.standard.url}`}/>
  <div className="banner_contents">
    {/* edge cases */}
    <h1 className="banner_title">
      {movie.title}
    </h1>
    <div className="banner_buttons">
      <button className="banner_button">Play</button>
      <button className="banner_button">Original</button>
    </div>
    <h1 className="banner_description">{movie.description}</h1>
  </div>
  <div className="banner--fadeBottom" />
</header>
):null;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting the error because before getting any data your movie object is empty . you should check before accessing nested properties . like this

```
 <img src ={movie.thumbnails ? `${movie.thumbnails.standard.url}` : ""}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`movie?.thumbnails?.standard?.url` should do it. Looks like `movie.thumbnails` is `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

assuming `movie` contains the correct data, the syntax should work. Here's a test: https://jsfiddle.net/yf470pma/1/

I would add a breakpoint and check what is really there.